# Boot stuck at "Started TLP system startup/shutdown."

Tags: boot, startup, kde-neon

OS: KDE Neon 5.14 based on Ubuntu 18.04
Kernel version: 4.15.0-42-generic

I tried booting from an older kernel version from the grub menu, still the system won't boot. It shows a long list of messages and doesn't proceed after the message

`Started TLP system startup/shutdown.`

Kernel was updated a few days ago. However, there was no problem booting after the update. I cannot identify what is causing this issue. Does it have something to do with the graphics driver?

Update: Running `startx` from the command line solved the issue. However, I would like to know what caused this issue.

Update 2: After reboot, the GRUB file is not found and system doesn't boot. I tried running the boot-repait utility and it fixed the grub. However the system boots into a black screen with a white blinking cursor, and does not show the login screen even after waiting for an hour.

Comment: How did you get to a prompt where you could run `startx` if the boot process gets stuck? Please can you clarify -- in your question.

Comment: I opened the prompt with Ctrl+Alt+F3

Comment: So it did boot - at least to a login prompt?

Comment: It is presently showing just a blank screen with a blinking cursor. However, I am able to access the login prompt at this stage.